# Plone-Theme navtree.css unknown source

Tags: css, plone

I created my own theme (not diazo) the classic way via terminal - I used most of the sunburst parts and redesigned them.

**The problem is** on my local computer and a vanilla plone 4.16 install everything works fine but on the server the theme uses parts for e.g. the navtree.css (in my theme empty) that seems to be part of the classic plone theme and I really don't know why.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the installation on your local machine differs from the one the server.

I only thing I could imagine with the given informations is, that you have a different theme active.

Go to the ZMI (plone root) -> portal_skins -> Properties (Tab).
Check which theme is active.

I guess in your case on the local machine it's `sunburst` and on the server it's `Plone theme classic`.

Please provide more informations if this is not the case.

Comment: Sry for the delay - the theme was right but the order was wrong. For some reason the custom folder which I didn't even specify is used. When I change the order it works fine. Thanks ;) 

Do u happen to know how to override the 'custom' folder with an empty one?

Comment: imho you cannot override the custom folder, but you can change the order, or remove it from the list defined in portal_skins. This can be done by GenericSetup (http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/templates_css/skin_layers.html#defining-a-skin-layer).